# Can ping URL but cannot access via cURL or wget

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, wget, ifconfig

I am experiencing an issue where I can `ping`, but I cannot use `wget` or `curl`. This is the output from these commands.

I have copied a working Vagrant VM from one Win7 PC to another and this is the issue I am having. Could this be a problem with my networking setup within VirtualBox?

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]# ping crmpicco.co.uk
PING crmpicco.co.uk (83.125.22.146) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 83.125.22.146: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=63.1 ms
64 bytes from 83.125.22.146: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=64.6 ms
64 bytes from 83.125.22.146: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=62.4 ms
^C
--- crmpicco.co.uk ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 62.460/63.427/64.686/0.954 ms
[vagrant@localhost ~]# wget http://www.crmpicco.co.uk
--2015-09-10 16:37:17--  http://www.crmpicco.co.uk/
Resolving www.crmpicco.co.uk (www.crmpicco.co.uk)... 83.125.22.146, 83.125.22.146
Connecting to www.crmpicco.co.uk (www.crmpicco.co.uk)|83.125.22.146|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
Connecting to www.crmpicco.co.uk (www.crmpicco.co.uk)|83.125.22.146|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

This is my current network setup:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]# ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feea:9bb5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:ea:9b:b5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 29  bytes 2813 (2.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 105  bytes 13412 (13.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.200  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe1d:5e16  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:1d:5e:16  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 389  bytes 40772 (39.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 228  bytes 36354 (35.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 497  bytes 56861 (55.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 497  bytes 56861 (55.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you surf to the web page in the VM from a regular browser?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, I can open Firefox and go to crmpicco.co.uk (and Github for that matter). I am using VirtualBox to manage the Virtual Machine. Could this be an issue with my network adapter setup in Virtualbox? As I say I literally copied my .vbox file onto a external HDD and then moved it onto the other host and then started it with Virtualbox (no other config changes made). I assumed this was the easiest way to move it across as I have a bunch of settings that I don't want to lose. Generally it seemed to go smoothly other than this networking problem.

Comment: If you can surf to it in FF, I can think of no network-related reason another web client (like wget or alike) couldn't contact it.  Have you tried removing and re-creating the network adapters on the VM?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Do you mean deleting the Network Adapters from the VirtualBox Network tab settings? I've updated the question to show the two adapters which are currently setup. Should I try deleting these and re-creating? I wondered if the `MAC Address` shown is a reference to the MAC address on my original Win7 host?

Comment: Yup, that's what I mean. :) Remove them from the VM (and from the guest OS) and create new ones. FYI -- MACs starting with 080027 are VirtualBox adapter MACs (see ["who is Cadmus Computer Systems?"](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.virtualbox.devel/2199))

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 There doesn't appear to be a way to remove them as such. I tried refeshing the MAC addresses before booting it up to see if that had any effect - but alas, no. :( I'm at a loss with this now...

Comment: Did you ever get this problem solved? The same problem suddenly started happening with my vagrant box. I can ping but can't curl from inside the vagrant box. But I can ping AND curl from the host machine.